# How to remove rounded from to select query in jquery?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

How to remove rounded corners and down arrow symbol from select box. And also Need to set width as 30% and need to set both select boxes in one row.

I need similar to following image,

[image]

Code:

```
<select name="color" class="test"> 
    <option>pick a color</option>  
    <option value="red">RED</option>
    <option value="blue">BLUE</option>  
</select>

<select name="color" class="test1"> 
    <option>pick a color</option>  
    <option value="red">RED</option>
    <option value="blue">BLUE</option>  
</select>
```

CSS:

```
select
{
     border-radius: none; 
    width: 30% !importent;
}
```

Fiddle URL, http://jsfiddle.net/Ramaganiprasad/2Lyvhqgg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the corners set the `data-corners="false"`

```
<select name="color" class="test" data-corners="false">
    <option>pick a color</option>
    <option value="red">RED</option>
    <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
</select>
```

To hide the arrow,

```
.ui-select .ui-icon {
    display:none;
}
```

To display in same line,

```
.ui-select{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lyvhqgg/1/)

Comment: But I need the down arrow symbol. Just similar to attached screenshot in my question

Comment: it is ups to you to change the look of the `.ui-select .ui-icon{}`